# Approval process determined by oppty amount

Tags: approval-process, opportunity

While creating an approval process for opptys, I need that upto certain amounts the approval process will go to a certain user, while for other/higher amounts, it will go to another person.

How can I establish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do this:

1. You can create two "steps" within an approval process, and specify the entry conditions for each step (e.g. step 1 might be Amount < 25000, step 2 might be >= 25000).

[image]

2. You can create two approval processes, each with a different entry condition, and one step each.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply set up multiple approval processes on the Opportunity object and add your amount constraints in the entry criteria for each approval process.  See below.  Each of these processes could specify the specific person you need for each scenario.

[image]